# change date while time is added

Tags: php, mysql

i searched alot about adding minutes and then change time but all is about adding minutes i have problem i receive time one is 12:00 and one is 4:00 i want to add 15 minutes to 12:00 and its reached to 4 then date should be change

```html
$nowtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$timeoflastlogin = $db->gettime();

//ADD 10 MINS TO TIME LAST ATTEMPTED 
$endtime = strtotime('+ 10 minutes', $timeoflastlogin );
//$endtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('+ 10 minutes', $timeoflastlogin );
```

Comment: `$timeoflastlogin` needs to be a unix timestamp in `strtotime()`.... what is it in this case?

Comment: sir i am fresh student of php sir what i said above is it possible if i receive 2 time variable and then alot 15 minutes and if its get complete time then date is changed

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that $timeoflastlogin is a unix timestamp you could use the following

```
<?php
$timeoflastlogin = $timeoflastlogin + (60 * 10); //Add 10 mins in seconds
?>
```